# Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between JavaScript's

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

and

```
window.location.reload()
```

functions?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `window.location.reload()` reloads the current page with POST data, while `window.location.href=window.location.href` does not include the POST data.

As noted by @W3Max in the comments below, `window.location.href=window.location.href` will not reload the page if there's an anchor (#) in the URL - You must use `window.location.reload()` in this case.

Also, as noted by @Mic below, `window.location.reload()` takes an additional argument `skipCache` so that with using `window.location.reload(true)` the browser will skip the cache and reload the page from the server. `window.location.reload(false)` will do the opposite, and load the page from cache if possible.

Comment: note that when you use window.location.reload() on a POST the browser will ask you if you want resend the data to reload the page

Comment: @Wimmel, is there a way to disable this message ?

Comment: window.location.href=window.location.href will not reload the page if there's an anchor (#) in the URL - You must use window.location.reload() in this case.

Comment: Also note that location.reload() will also force reload all static content (much like a ctrl+f5 style hard refresh) whereas setting location.href back to href (or pathname or URL) does not, which could be a significant (and unnecessary) difference in load time on some pages.

Comment: @Wimmel Chrome: reloads the page with a GET
Firefox: re-executes the previous request, meaning if it was a POST, you'll get the nice popup asking you about whether to resend the data or not

Comment: If you need to modify the url without reloading and without a '#' you could use window.history.pushState(state, title, URL);

Comment: You can use `location.href=location.search` and it will work even with `#` in URL.

Answer (score 56):

If you say `window.location.reload(true)` the browser will skip the cache and reload the page from the server. `window.location.reload(false)` will do the opposite.

Note: `default` value for `window.location.reload()` is `false`

Comment: @Ismail - The default is false.

Comment: Google Chrome 32, while using webRTC the true/false did not worked for me. I had a iframe with webRTC and only using `window.location.href = window.location.href` did the trick.

Comment: If you have made changes to a form on the page, the changes _may_ disappear (revert to cached values) depending on the browser when using `location.reload()` or `location.reload(false)`. To do a complete refresh of the page, use `location.reload(true)`.

Comment: Note that the `forceGet` parameter for `location.reload()` is [only available in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#location.reload_has_no_parameter)!

Answer (score 33):

The difference is that

```
window.location = document.URL;
```

will not reload the page if there is a hash (#) in the URL (with or without something after it), whereas

```
window.location.reload();
```

will reload the page.

Comment: Not all browsers have this issue with ending hases. If ending hashes are a concern for you, try: window.location = document.URL.replace(/#$/, '');

Comment: At least Chrome is concerned. I used to take `location.href = location.href` for granted, but I just noticed that exact behavior and came to SO to spread the word. Just use `location.reload()` instead.

Comment: You can also use window.location.pathname instead of writing such regular expression. For example: `window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);`

Answer (score 20):

If you add the boolean true to the reload
`window.location.reload(true)` it will load from server.

It is not clear how supported this boolean is, [W3Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location-methods) mentions that NS *used to support* it

There MIGHT be a difference between the content of window.location.href and [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.URL) - there at least used to be a difference between location.href and the non-standard and deprecated [document.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location) that had to do with redirection, but that is really last millennium.

For documentation purposes I would use [window.location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#reload) because that is what you want to do.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5091619/429972 since this explains the difference.

Answer (score 16):

As said, modifying the href when there is a hash (#) in the url would not reload the page. Thus, I use this to reload it instead of regular expressions:

```
if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
} else {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Came across this question researching some aberrant behavior in IE, specifically IE9, didn't check older versions. It seems

```
window.location.reload();
```

results in a refresh that blanks out the entire screen for a second, where as

```
 window.location = document.URL;
```

refreshes the page much more quickly, almost imperceptibly.

Doing a bit more research, and some experimentation with fiddler, it seems that `window.location.reload()` will bypass the cache and reload from the server regardless if you pass the boolean with it or not, this includes getting all of your assets (images, scripts, style sheets, etc) again. So if you just want the page to refresh the HTML, the `window.location = document.URL` will return much quicker and with less traffic.

A difference in behavior between browsers is that when IE9 uses the reload method it clears the visible page and seemingly rebuilds it from scratch, where FF and chrome wait till they get the new assets and rebuild them if they are different.

Comment: window.location = document.URL reloads the page just like window.location.reload(). Is there a state of the art for refreshing without scrolling back to the top, or imperceptibly as you said?

Answer (score 6):

A difference in Firefox (12.0) is that on a page rendered from a POST, reload() will pop up a warning and do a re-post, while a URL assignment will do a GET.

Google Chrome does a GET for both.

Comment: Chrome 38 now seems to use POST for .reload().

Answer (score 3):

Using JSF, I'm now having the issue with refresh after session is expired: [PrimeFaces ViewExpiredException after page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252234/primefaces-viewexpiredexception-after-page-reload) and with some investigation I have found one difference in FireFox:

Calling `window.location.reload()` works like clicking refresh icon on FF, it adds the line

`Cache-Control  max-age=0`

while setting `window.location.href` works like pressing ENTER in URL line, it does not send that line.

Though both are sent as GET, the first (reload) is restoring the previous data and the application is in inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

No, there shouldn't be. However, it's possible there is differences in some browsers, so either (or neither) may not work in some case.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience of about 3 years, i could not find any difference...

edit : yes, as one of them here has said, only passing a boolean parameter to window.location.reload() is the difference.
if you pass *true*, then the browser loads a fresh page,
but if *false*, then the cache version is loaded...

Answer (score 0):

In our case we just want to reload the page in webview and for some reasons we couldn't find out why!
We try almost every solution that has been on the web, but stuck with no reloading using location.reload() or alternative solutions like window.location.reload(), 
location.reload(true), ...!

Here is our simple solution :

Just use a < a > tag with the empty "href" attribution value like this :

```
< a href="" ...>Click Me</a>
```

(in some cases you have to use "return true" on click of the target to trigger reload)

For more information check out this question :
[Is an empty href valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637969/is-an-empty-href-valid)

Answer (score -4):

window.location.href, this as saved my life in webview from Android 5.1. The page don't reload with location.reload() in this version from Android.