# What are possible differences between window.location.reload() and window.location = document.URL?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Is there any difference between these two lines of code, if yes, please enlighten me.

1.

```
window.location.reload();
```

2.

```
window.location = document.URL;
```