# Mouse pointer on hover of Twitter Bootstrap dropdown nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

When I hover over the dropdown in my navbar, the mouse changes to the text pointer instead of the hand pointer that should show for a link.

Here's my html:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
      World vs. World
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><%= link_to 'Current Match', current_match_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'All NA Matches', wvw_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

We're missing your CSS, but I would go for a simple `cursor: pointer` :

```
.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: In bootstrap 4, you can use:   `.nav-item a:hover {  cursor: pointer }`

Comment: For bootstrap 4, it may be more specific to use `a:not([href]).dropdown-toggle:hover { cursor: pointer;}`. Nitpicky, but this allows you to use an alternate cursor for dropdowns vs regular links.

Answer (score 21):

An alternative to `cursor:pointer` is adding an inert `href` attribute for the `<a>`, e.g. `href="#"` (although [some object to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572522/sole-hash-in-anchor-href)).

Comment: if you want to have the same ui style while at the same time handling any navigation without the use of href then use <a href="">myTitle</a>

Comment: Just a warning to others, I used the `href="#"` on a dropdown at the middle of a page and it would scroll back to the top of the page every time I clicked an option. Kind of annoying behavior.

Comment: FYI: If you return `false` in the `onclick` event it will not scroll back to the top. ( `onclick="return false;"`)

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4:

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please, improve your answer with more explanation. It will be great if your answer will be clear for anyone with alike problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 5.x

You can replace `<a>` element with `button`, they have pointer cursor on hover. Just make sure to add `dropdown-item` class.

```
<button class="dropdown-item" onclick="someFunc()">Do something</button>
```