# Use a blank link but not jump to top of page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a blank link to toggle a div through Jquery and in the link I have a blank link which allows you to click on the text to toggle the div but when you click toggle text the page jumps to the top. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<a href="#" id="searchAnchor">Search Options</a>
```

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572522/sole-hash-in-anchor-href

Answer (score 2):

Use an `<input type="button">` if you don't want the functionality of a link. Style it to look however you like.

(Alternatively, call `preventDefault()` on the event object, but that still leaves you with a link that isn't a link).