# How to add url parameter to the current url?

Tags: html, url

Currently I'm at

```
http://example.com/topic.php?id=14
```

and I want to make a link to

```
http://example.com/topic.php?id=14&like=like
```

by not defining the current url. Like `<a href="&like=like">Like</a>`. However this last one shows me `http://example.com/&like=like`

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899097/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-the-url

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no way to write a relative URI that preserves the existing query string while adding additional parameters to it.

You have to:

```
topic.php?id=14&like=like
```

Comment: There are many ways. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899097/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-the-url for how to using Javascript.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the path. Starting with ? is okay. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7871871/62421

Comment: What about using `<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&filter=2'; ?>">` ?

Comment: @rambodrahmani — This isn't a PHP question and that is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 17):

```
function currentUrl() {
    $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
    $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    return $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
}
```

Then add your value with something like;

```
echo currentUrl().'&value=myVal';
```

Answer (score 16):

I know I'm late to the game, but you can just do `?id=14&like=like` by using http build query as follows:

```
http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("like"=>"like")))
```

Whatever GET parameters you had will still be there and if `like` was a parameter before it will be overwritten, otherwise it will be included at the end.

Comment: This is php only

Comment: You are correct, and I can't believe I didn't realize this question wasn't a PHP question. I just assumed it was because another answer was also given in PHP :/

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to add the URL parameter in JavaScript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542008/258772). As suggested there, you can use the [`URLSeachParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) API in modern browsers as follows:

```html
<script>
function addUrlParameter(name, value) {
  var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  searchParams.set(name, value)
  window.location.search = searchParams.toString()
}
</script>

<body>
...
  <a onclick="addUrlParameter('like', 'like')">Like this page</a>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is [not elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/860099) but possible to do it as one-liner `<a>` element

```html
<a href onclick="event.preventDefault(); location+='&like=like'">Like</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use "like" as a parameter your link needs to be:

```
<a href="/topic.php?like=like">Like</a>
```

More likely though is that you want:

```
<a href="/topic.php?id=14&like=like">Like</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write a function as follows:

```
var addParams = function(key, val, url) {
  var arr = url.split('?');
  if(arr.length == 1) {
    return url + '?' + key + '=' + val;
  }
  else if(arr.length == 2) {
    var params = arr[1].split('&');
    var p = {};
    var a = [];
    var strarr = [];
    $.each(params, function(index, element) {
      a = element.split('=');
      p[a[0]] = a[1];
      })
    p[key] = val;
    for(var o in p) {
      strarr.push(o + '=' + p[o]);
    }
    var str = strarr.join('&');
    return(arr[0] + '?' + str);
  }
}
```