# PHP add another get method to url after submiting

Tags: php, get

I have an search method who redirect to something like this:

```
mysite.ro/search.php?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

When i have pagination i need to redirect me to something like this:

```
mysite.ro/search.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&page=2
```

I dont know the solution to have an href who redirect to page=2 and keep the same search criteria.
I tried `<a href="&page=2">` and `href="<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];?>&page=1" not usefull both.`

Comment: A very quick Google search lead me here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562701/1476763

Comment: Is not working... After multiple clicking i have something like this: &page=2&page=2&page=2&page=3 and counting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Its worked for me.

```
<?php

 $actual_link = '';
 $delimiter = '?&page=';
 $link = array();
 $actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $links = explode($delimiter, $actual_link);
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $links[0];?>?&page=1" >Link </a>
```

Comment: Same problem, after multiple clicking i have something like this: &page=2&page=2&page=2&page=3 and counting