# Meaning of "#" when it is used like this href="#"

Tags: html, debugging, url, web, scrapy

I have been following this [tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy) to learn how to use Scrapy. I am using [greenbook](http://www.thegreenbook.com/products/air-compressors-oil-lubricated/page/1/) as my sample site to test out the web scraping. One of the function: SgmlLinkExtractor takes in a parameter which is the href of the "next" page button . The problem is  that for greenbook , the href for the "next" page button is a "#" if you inspect the element via firefox

These are my questions

1) What does "#" mean when used in this way : href="#"

2) How do i solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `href="#"` means the same as `href=""`, i.e. a reference to the start of the current document. It is seldom used with the intention of linking to the start, however. Instead, it is used a placeholder that makes the `a` element formally a link, and also a link from styling point of view, but in a context where the element is expected to have an `onclick` event handler or to have its `href` value overwritten.

Cf. to [Is an empty href valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637969/is-an-empty-href-valid/5637990#5637990) and [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

In your case, it sounds like the software you are using generates next page “links” that are not real links but driven by JavaScript and carrying `href="#"` as a placeholder only. This does not work with other software that expects `href` attributes to be real. It depends on both pieces of software whether and how you can make them work together.

Comment: How do they bring me to another page when the href="#"

Comment: With JavaScript, as explained in my answer.

Comment: i guess this link which is exactly the same explaination as yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0?rq=1 explains it all. My guess is that they are using jquery function for the next page

Answer (score 2):

You can use `#` to point to an `ID` on the page rather than redirect to a `URL`.

When you see stuff like "Click `here` to scroll to the bottom of the page`

The `here` href will be `#bottomOfPage`

http://jsfiddle.net/2q3NJ/

Comment: in my case its just href="#" , its not href="bottomOfPage"