# HTTPS security is compromised by (null) - what causes this?

Tags: internet-explorer, https

I am encountering the following error in IE 11:

```
HTTPS security is compromised by (null) - what causes this?
```

I am creating a popup (iframe) by clicking on a link, and this popup is causing the error.

I have read up on this error, and I understand that it is caused by mixed content. I have checked and all file includes also use https. Usually the specific file that is compromising security is mentioned, but in this case it is **(null)**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question after an interesting debugging journey:

It turns out that the popup that was not displaying due to the HTTPS security error wrote a piece of html in the body onload event handler. In this html snippet were two links with **href=""**; IE 11 sees this as a security issue.

To fix I replaced **href=""** with **href="javascript:;"** (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637969/is-an-empty-href-valid)).

Answer (score 0):

See this note from Microsoft:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1925265/document-write-leads-sec7111-https-security-is-compromised-by-null-error-in-ie11-doc-mode-9-11-for-all-https-pages

You could use the document.createElement() and document.body.appendChild() instead of document.write to avoid this problem.

Comment: This link no longer works because Microsoft Connect has been retired.  Paraphrasing would have been useful at this point.