# link onclick and input[type='button'] onclick behaves differently?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a piece of code where there's a link and a input button both calling a same onclick function. However, they behave differently.

```
<input type="button" onclick="undelete_this(&quot;profile.php&quot;, 42)" value="Undelete">

<a href="" onclick="undelete_this(&quot;profile.php&quot;,42)"><strong>here</strong></a>


function undelete_this(url, id){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to undelete this record?")){
        if(id!=="" && id!=0){
            var info = 'id=' + id +"&action=undelete";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: info,
                success: function(){
                    window.location.href = ($(location).attr('pathname')+"?enter=false&id="+id);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception, realexception) {
                        alert(jqXHR.responseText+" "+realexception);
                }
            }
            )
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

when the button is clicked, the ajax status is success; but when the link is clicked, the ajax status is error (error code = 0) and the responseText is blank.

Is there anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because having an empty `href` causes the page to be reloaded when the link is clicked. Reloading the page (generally: navigating to any URL) aborts any outstanding AJAX requests, which is why you get no response.

Possible solutions:

- `onclick="undelete_this(&quot;profile.php&quot;,42); return false;"` will cancel the default action (reloading the page)
- `href="javascript:;"` will make the default action a no-op, again preventing the page from being reloaded

Comment: The return false doesnt work neither (I had that piece in the undelete_this function)
I end up putting href="#" so that there's no page refreshing.

Comment: @SixinLi: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/MH9j9/) (the alert appears after 2 sec, so obviously no navigation has taken place). In any case, [you should prefer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5637969/50079) `javascript:;` over the `#` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply leave the href blank, because `href=''` is a link back to the current page (ie it causes a **page refresh**).

There is a way of making a link do absolutely nothing when clicked (unless Javascript events are bound to it).

```
<a href="javascript:undelete_this(&quot;profile.php&quot;,42);"><strong>here</strong></a>
```