# Under what conditions does href="#" cause scrolling to the top of the page?

Tags: html, web, href

I was using `<a href="#" onclick="f();">click here</a>` type tags to trigger actions on my website. I swear they didn't used to do this, but now when I click one of them, the browser scrolls to the top of the page.

Having found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637969/is-an-empty-href-valid) answer, I am now using `href="javascript:;"` which works great. But I can't be the only one with this problem (unless I am). I'd really love to know when `href="#"` behaves this way and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always, unless your javascript handler prevents it.

```
function f(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now if your click calls `f(e)` you will not scroll to the top.

Comment: What is `e` in this context -- an event object? How would I use this function inside an `href`?

Comment: @EliRose You wouldn't.  In the `href` case where you have the `javascript:` protocol handler, the context is disconnected from the event.  At a minimum, you would use `onclick` and then you could use any JS you wanted.

Comment: You're right, of course -- I said `href`, but was thinking `onlick`. How do I access the event object from within `onlick`?

Comment: If the function you call is expecting the `event` argument (as the example above is), it will just be there. You don't need to explicitly pass it to the `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

They always do this.

Note that the click action of your links can be overridden in JavaScript, which is why you may have seen different behavior before.