# Javascript variable not acting global

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm just learning Javascript after starting out in PHP.

I'm trying some basic stuff, but for some reason the below code doesn't act as I expect.  I have researched it, and from what I can tell it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
showIndex=4;

function test(){
showIndex++;
alert(showIndex);
}
</script>
```

I am calling the script with an image:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:25px;">';
<a href="" onclick="test()" ><img src="_images/next.png" width="100" />    </a>
</div>
```

It runs fine the first time, but when I hit the button again, it still has the initial variable plus one. (which makes me think it's acting as a local variable...)
It seem so straight forward... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to set the `href` of that link and you'll see why :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<a>` and have the event on the image, it's refreshing the page. You don't need to have it wrapped in an `<a>` tag for a `onclick` event:

```
<img src="_images/next.png" onclick="test()" width="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty link [just reloads the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676563). You can insert `#` in it:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:25px;">
   <a href="#" onclick="test()" >www </a>
</div>
```

Then everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The empty href attribute on the `<a>` tag is messing you up.  Either remove the href attribute, or change it to `#` or `javascript:void(0)`

Alternatively, you can call your method from the href attribute like this

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:25px;">';
     <a href="javascript:test()" ><img src="_images/next.png" width="100" />    </a>
</div>
```