# Is there an empty URI?

Tags: parsing, uri

I working on a routine that parses a URI. Among obvious cases there is an empty string case. Is the empty string a valid input? What would be an outcome URI of an empty string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An empty string can’t possibly be a URI. The [general URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) specifies that at least the `scheme` component followed by a `:` followed by the `hier-part` component (which may be empty) must be present.

But a **relative URI reference** can be empty. The syntax of [relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) specifies that at least the `relative-part` component must be present, but it’s allowed to be empty (`path-empty`).

An *empty* relative URI reference is a [same-document reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.4) (bold emphasis mine):

> The most frequent examples of same-document references are **relative references that are empty** or include only the number sign ("#") separator followed by a fragment identifier.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse an empty `String` to a `Uri` without an exception but its fields will be null or their default invalid values.

```
val myUri = Uri.parse("")
```

`myUri.host` is `null` and
`myUri.port` is `-1`

Comment: "Uri.Parse" has been deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Uri.Parse?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Since the root of a URI is a limited set we know it does not have a valid root.
It therefore does not identify anything and is invalid as an identifier. But this might have a meaning in your context still since tere is no specific standard for a URI.