What does an empty string do to `location.replace`?
Is this usage correct?
What is the expected behavior?
Is it browser compatible?


location.replace('');




So now the question is closed as "not focused enough"? Come on ladies and gentlemen, those 3 questions don't confuse any thinking human, just add clarity, so that a helpful answer can be more specific and detailed enough. Just because you are incompetent for answering the question, it is perfectly possible for someone who is here to help. You are not helpful at all. The question already has a clear focus on the usage of location.replace with an empty string parameter. If the complexity of this question is too much for you, leave it for others, instead of misusing the closing function of SO.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338457/535480 - your empty string is a relative uri reference.

Takes you to the current page.

Thank you. Does it have any browser compatibility issues in modern and older browsers? Or can I use it confidently?

If an URI can't be empty, the location.replace("") should throw a SyntaxError, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace. That's why I'm a bit hesitant to use the empty string.

"Takes you to the current page" - Not necessarily so: it will use GET even if POST was used to load the page. Also it will discard URL parameters like ?search=bla&page=5.
