# How to explicitly state the port number in an absolute URL?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, port

The question I'm working on:

- mypage.html is stored in the folder Alice, in the folder Web Pages, in Root.
- logo.jpg is stored in the folder IMG, in the folder Resources, in Web Pages, in Root.
- Write the tag that will display the logo in mypage.html using an absolute url with scheme "http" and port "80".

Now, I (approximately) do most of this:

```html
<img src="http:/webpages/resources/img/logo.jpg">
```

However I cannot find an example of how or where to specify the port number using a path like this.

Could anyone help point out to me where to include it? (And also if my progress above is actually correct?)

Comment: Http://whatever:80/something.jpg

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state the port, 80 is the default for HTTP.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL (BTW, your current URL is missing a slash after the protocol).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port comes directly after the hostname, separated by `:`.

```html
http://example.com:80/
```

```html
http://example.com:80/path
```

[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340108/1591669) specifications:

- IETF’s URI standard: [`port` subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) (part of the [`authority` component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2))
- WHATWG’s URL standard: [`scheme-relative-special-URL string`](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-special-url-string)

Comment: That makes sense, however I'm a little unsure how to apply this to my specific example. Would it be http ://Root:80/webpages/... or http://:80/webpages/... or http ://webpages:80/... ?

Comment: @Jonathan: The hostname has to come first (and can’t be empty, like in your second example). A hostname is something like `example.com` or `www.example.org` or `localhost` etc. Can’t tell for sure what it should be in your case. But assuming that "webpages" is part of the URL path, it’s likely "root".

Answer (score 0):

http = Hypertext Transfer Protocol, use port 80 as default. You don't need to put :80 after the domain.

You need '/' after the http protocol:

```
<img src="http://webpages/resources/img/logo.jpg">
```

If the image is on the same server, you can use this:

```
<img src="resources/img/logo.jpg">
```

You're pointing to the resources folder, if your folder is on a lower folder level, you can use:

```
<img src="../resources/img/logo.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that port 80 is the default for http but the question I'm answering seems to request that port 80 is explicitly stated rather than implicitly.