# Is empty string valid value for React Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm writing a [React.js](http://React%20%E2%80%93%20A%20JavaScript%20library%20for%20building%20user%20interfaces%20%20https://reactjs.org/) application where I want to use `Link` component from react-router package in order to conditionally redirect a user to another page. If some condition doesn't hold I set the `to` prop to empty string which works and doesn't cause page reload and the page stays in the exact same place it was. But I'm wondering if this is the best practice?

This is my solution:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

<Link to={condition === true ? '/some/other/url' : ''}>
    <div>
        my content
    </div>
</Link>
```

I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) regarding empty string input.

Comment: It will eventually land you to the homepage when you will click.

Comment: @SwapnilShukla it doesn't land to the homepage

Answer (score 10):

I've never linked something to nothing in HTML or React. That said, it seems you have few options:

**Option 1**
Conditionally render the `div` not the `to` attribute. If codition is true show `Link` with div if not show div with no `Link`. This is probably the more "common" way to do this. If your `div` is not as simple as 'My Content' I would move it into a functional Component. And use that component instead of `<div>MyContent</div>` shown below.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

{ condition ? 
   (
     <Link to='/some/other/url'>
      <div>My Content</div>
     </Link>
   ) : ( <div>My Content</div> )
}
```

**Option 2**
Do what you did but use the `#` instead of an empty string.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

<Link to={condition === true ? '/some/other/url' : '#'}>
    <div>
        my content
    </div>
</Link>
```

**Option 3** Disable the link if the condition is false.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

//a better name might be in order here
const handleLinkDisable = (e) => {
  const { condition }  = this.state; //just assuming it comes from state
  if(condition){ e.preventDefault(); }
}; 

<Link to='/some/other/url' onClick={handleLinkDisable}>
  <div>My Content</div>
</Link>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I like your option 3, it works without causing a page refresh. There're a few issues with your code: 1) `condition ? null : e.preventDefault();` is neither an assignment nor a call, js will not compile. I used `if (condition) {e.preventDefault()}`. 2) storing className in state would cause a rerender each time the button is clicked. 3) css disabling link color should be placed on Link element. Please update (at least change the line which will not compile) the answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

`to` is a required prop for `Link`. If the url is empty better to hide the whole component:

```
   {
      condition && (
        <Link to={"/some/other/url"}>
          <div>my content</div>
        </Link>
      );
    }
```

If for some weird reason you need to have empty url, you can pass a space:

```
<Link to={condition === true ? '/some/other/url' : ' '}> // Whitespace here
    <div>
        my content
    </div>
</Link>
```

Comment: but if the condition is false then I need to copy the content and show it anyway which is code duplication especially if there's a lot of code inside the `div`

Comment: having whitespace works as well but do you have any reference which supports that it's a valid value for `to`?

Comment: `Link` uses `a` html element, so anything which is valid `href` should be also supported by `Link`.

Comment: Also if you look at the prop type of Link's `to` in the source code: `to: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]).isRequired`

Comment: But according to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7676563/5863693 `href=""` reloads the page which doesn't happen in my environment. According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340108/5863693 "an empty URI reference within a document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document" which again doesn't happen in my environment.

Comment: Link uses React routing, not the browser's one. That's why when you click on Link your page doesn't get reloaded, which is the case with normal `a` tag.

Comment: ok but why do you suggest to have whitespace and just empty string?

Comment: You'd get a warning if you use empty link: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4141

Comment: The solution stopped working for me. No changes were made to the code but now when I click at the `div` when the condition is false the page is refreshed. The component is wrapped in `withRouter` so React routing should be available.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a look at the [latest documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) and I think I understand what is going on with an empty string for the `to` prop of a Link component. Since that is the question here, I will try to explain.

According to the docs, if the `to` value doesn't start with a slash (`/`) then it is considered a relative link and the following is the expected behavior:

> A relative  value (that does not begin with /) resolves relative to the parent route, which means that it builds upon the URL path that was matched by the route that rendered that .

Unfortunately this doesn't mean that an empty string will just link to the URL you are already on. If you had a route like this:

```
<Route path="/questions/:id" element={<MyElement />} />
```

and a URL like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586239/is-empty-string-valid-value-for-react-link
```

the 'match' part is just `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586239`, and this is what the Link with empty `to` will link you to. In fact you will see it as the href of the `<a>` element.

Even if your matched route exactly equals the current URL, so it seems like empty string trick might work, each Link click will create an entry in the navigation history which will mess up navigating backwards and forwards if the intention is for the link to be a no-op.

This last point means that even using a trick like `<Link to={window.location.href}>` won't work because it will still pollute the navigation history.

There are plenty of good alternative suggestions as answers to this question that will work, but I wanted to try to answer why empty string as `to` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<BUTTON>` instead, you will have same pseudo like :active, :focus as link and  it will get rid of warnings.

generally install: eslint; sonarlint  extenstion... they will give you recommendation and industry standards for small errros like this.

Answer (score -2):

Use "javascript.void(0)" instead of using an empty string.

import {Link} from 'react-router';

mycontent

Kindly refer to docs [What does "javascript:void(0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Comment: This will trigger `Script URL is a form of eval no-script-url` lint error.

Comment: void simply returns undefined, which means to do nothing.

Comment: you will get something like `Warning: A future version of React will block javascript: URLs as a security precaution. Use event handlers instead if you can. If you need to generate unsafe HTML try using dangerouslySetInnerHTML instead. React was passed "javascript:void(0)".`