# React router, a link that leads nowhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In HTML I can use `<a href="#"></a>` or `<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>` to create a link that doesn't lead anywhere. How do I do the same thing with react-router `Link`'s `to` property? It's not allowed to pass `undefined` or `null`, only a string or an object. Passing `#` doesn't work, passing empty string results in the same behavior as if I passed `/`. I need to do it conditionally, so sometimes `Link` will have a real pathname and sometimes it should be empty, so I cannot use normal `a` element. The work-arounds I thought of were to render `a` instead of `Link` conditionally or pass a function like

```
(location: Location) => ({ ...location, href: '#' })
```

to the `to` property, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is empty string valid value for React Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586239/is-empty-string-valid-value-for-react-link)

Comment: @vivalldi, no, I wrote that empty string is treated as `/` in the `Link` component, so it redirects user to the main page of my app and I just want it to do nothing

Comment: Correct, and option 2 in the top answer shows how you could conditionally set the link

Comment: @vivalldi, but if I set `to` property to an empty string or a space, pressing the link redirects user to main page of my application, the `/` route. I don't want this, I want the link to do nothing. Like I have a page `/profile` I want to press the link and stay at `/profile` and using space as `to` attribute will change route to `/`

Comment: In that case, just use option 3. You add a `onClick` handler that checks the condition. If condition, then prevent default to prevent navigation (might be some issues with the `preventDefault` but I would have to dive into react router docs to find out the specifics

Comment: @AlexChashin Add a css class to the link when there is no url that has `pointer-events: none !important`