# refresh page after jquery/javascript event?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please show me how i can add an automatic page refresh after the following jquery event has taken place?

Thanks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".infobox-forum").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $("infobox-forum").remove();
            });         
        }, 2000);
     });         
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `location.reload()` to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".infobox-forum").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("infobox-forum").remove();
            location.reload(); // <---
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Another posibility is to use `window.location.href = window.location.href` instead. To decide which one to choose, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location).

Comment: also `window.location.href = window.location.href`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location

Comment: @house9 no need for `.href` You can just use `window.location`