# Javascript: Refresh parent page without entirely reloading

Tags: javascript, html

After a user has logged in via a fancybox (javascript) popup I wish to reload the parent page so they can access the logged in features.

Currently I am doing this with:

```
<a href="javascript:window.top.location.reload(true)" class="continue">Continue</a>
```

This works great, but the only issue is that it completely reloads the entire page: redownloads all the css & javascipt, etc.

All I want to do is reload the page normally, not a full refresh. How can I achieve this?

(I do not know the exact URL because the login can be done from any page via the fancybox, so I can't hardcode the URL.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another way of reloading the page i have seen in the *facebook graph api* is the following:

```
window.location = window.location
```

or in your case:

```
window.top.location = window.top.location
```

This solution reloads the page without trying to resend a `POST` request. Might be useful. for more information look at the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location).

Comment: Ah this is very fast. Just reloads the HTML only. Exactly what I want, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not to work when there is a hashtag in the URL (at least on my Firefox 26).

Comment: Then you could use something like the following: `window.top.location = (window.top.location.hostname + window.top.location.pathname)`. Should work in any browser (source http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

Comment: mate, thanks. so damn simple, yet effective solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
location.replace(location.href.split('#')[0]);
```

The `split` on hash is required, otherwise an url with a hash will not be refreshed.

If you want to keep the previous load in browser history, use [`assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) instead of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).

`href` is not currently supported by Opera, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href).