# Reset everything to their initial state without exiting fullscreen window?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a 0-21 solitaire game with multiple levels. When the player completes a level, I need to reset everything to their initial state, so I use `window.location.reload()`. But this method causes some inconveniences in the game like *exiting fullscreen window.*

So what I need is a method that **resets everything to their initial state**, just like refreshing the page, but **without refreshing the page**. Is that possible? *(With pure javascript.)*

Or alternatively, a way to **refresh the page without exiting fullscreen window** would also do the job.

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897434/javascript-refresh-parent-page-without-entirely-reloading

Comment: Generally, we need to see code to help.

Comment: @atulw Unfortunately, it does the same thing as `window.location.reload()`. So it also exits fullscreen window.

Comment: @ErcanTomaç would it be acceptable to just re-enter fullscreen mode after reloading ?

Comment: @Programmer I tried it by doing this: `window.location.reload(); requestFullScreen();`. But it didn't work since `requestFullScreen()` method requires a "user interaction" like clicking a button etc. At least I assume the reason it's not working is this.