# Why location.reload() is slower than the other page reload methods?

Tags: javascript

Few months ago I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259514/1420197) about how to refresh the page via JavaScript.

I provided a [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hE6Ua/) too:

```
var solutions = [
    function () { location.reload(); },
    function () { history.go(0); },
    function () { location.href = location.href; },
    function () { location.href = location.pathname; },
    function () { location.replace(location.pathname); },
    function () { location.reload(false); },
];

$("[data-func]").on("click", function () {
    solutions[parseInt($(this).attr("data-func"))]();
});
```

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery/17259514#comment25071535_17259514) noticed that `location.reload()` is slower than the other methos. Now I can see the same thing.

Why is it slower? Why the others are faster?

Comment: "window.location.reload() reloads the current page with POST data, while window.location.href=window.location.href does not include the POST data." This is probably where the performance difference arise from - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location

Comment: @MarkWalters That may be an explanation, but where is this specified in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload)?

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location-reload

Comment: @MarkWalters - Yes Even i dont see where its mentioned in Documentation ????

Comment: @IonicăBizău Did my answer help at all?

Comment: @matt1985 Thanks! Not a fan of W3Schools, tho, but thanks for reminding me. I probably missed to accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been looking for this myself and the best reference I could find is actually on w3schools.com

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

> location.reload(*forceGet*)
>
> *forceGet*:
>
> **false** - Default. Reloads the current page from the cache.
>
> **true** - The current page must be reloaded from the server

Comment: Please do not use w3schools, as they are not canon. Here's a more-authoritative link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: At the time I was looking for something a little more solid than w3schools but they seemed to have the simplest version of the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the Mozilla Developement Network I guess the `.reload` method may fetch all files from the Server again. This would be similar to a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> reload.

The `location.href` for example, simply follows the link which may be cached. As for the MDN definition the behave is not clearly defined so I guess its browser and case specific behave.