# Add onclick to element, but keep current onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Is it possible to add a javascript event to a DOM element that already has a onclick event, but I want to keep that event property.

I have radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="checkout-payment" value="56" id="checkout-payment-56" class="checkout-radio checkout-payment-radio checkout-payment-radio" onclick="paymentChanged(this);" />
```

in which I want to add

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

while keeping the original onclick, but I have no access to the html, I can only modify through javascript.

so my desired code will be

```
<input type="radio" name="checkout-payment" value="56" id="checkout-payment-56" class="checkout-radio checkout-payment-radio checkout-payment-radio" onclick="paymentChanged(this); window.location.href=window.location.href" />
```

Comment: In the code you provided, the _onclick_ event you want to add is already present in the HTML. Is it the case in the original code?

Comment: @blex yes this is the original code in the first code field. the second one is what i want it to look like. my first post had a error as i by mistake posted the desired code instead of the current code. i have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out there was a much simpler way to acheive my desired result.

```
    $( '.webshop-checkout input[type="radio"]' ).click(function() {
  location.reload(true);
});
```

i am sorry i was not clear in my original post, and it has been edited.

Comment: That would be a way to do it, just keep [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var curHandler = $('#checkout-payment-56').attr("onclick");
    $('#checkout-payment-56')[0].onclick = null;
    $('#checkout-payment-56').click(function () {
       window.location.href=window.location.href;
    });
```

Comment: Or, in plain javascript `document.getElementById('checkout-payment-56').addEventListener("click", function(){window.location.href=window.location.href;});`.

Comment: @blex, yes, that's also possible ;)

Comment: I edited the answer to compensate for storing the inline click event.

Comment: You do store it, but never reuse it?

Comment: if OP was me (i guess it means original poster? xD) then i am trying to add a onclick to a dom that already has onclick function, but without removing the already onclick.. its a closed ecommerce system so i have no access to the html markup so i figured using JS would be more appropriate. but im not that good at js yet..

Comment: Then just add another handler with .click(), this doesn't overwrite the original behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

in function, lets call it

`onRadioButtonClick()`

then, just do

```
var self = this; //keep the context of the file
$("[name=checkout-payment]").on('click', function () {
       onRadioButtonClick.call(self); //call the method with the normal context.
      //continue code..

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this to every `.webshop-checkout input[type="radio"]`, you could do it that way:

```
$('.webshop-checkout input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
});
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RzyEv/2/)

Comment: Thanks alot, this will work. But is it not possible to make it "universal" ? the problem with this solution is that each input has their own onclick attribute, and i need it to fit to all radio inputs on that page (by the body class and input[type=radio]). so that .webshop-checkout input[type="radio"] will have that onclick added eventhough it already has one.

Comment: @SolidSnake ok, I edited the code, would this suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#checkout-payment-56" ).bind( "click", function(evt) {
       console.log('that works');
     //sessionStorage.setItem(evt.target.id,evt.target.className);
    });
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer to include explaination.