# jquery page not reloading (location.reload)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My page is not refreshing after the success message is echoed from the query. I've tried location.reload(), location.reload(true) and even tried to redirect using header in 'loginFunction.php' page, but nothing seems to work.

JQuery

```
if ($.trim(user) != '' && password != '') {
    $.post('includes/loginFunction.php', {
        userName: user,
        uPassword: password
    }, function(data) {
        var result = data;

        if (data !== "success") {
            $('#uNameE').text(data);
        } else {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP

```
require_once('dbopen.php');
    if(isset($_POST['userName']) === true && empty ($_POST['userName']) === false ){
        $userName = $_POST["userName"];
        $userPass = $_POST["uPassword"];

        $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE userN = '$userName' AND password = '$userPass'");
        $num = $query->num_rows;

        if($num != 0 ){ 
            $_SESSION['usernameP'] = $userName;
             //Header not working neither
             //header('location: index.php');
            echo "success";
        }

        else{
            echo "Username or password incorrect";
        }       
}
```

Comment: True just asserts that the page shouldn't be loaded from cache.

Comment: thanks for letting me know

Comment: are there any other javascript errors on the page according to your browse console?

Comment: See console if there is any error.

Comment: console has no errors

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your `.reload()` is `POST`ing again on page reload which may result in a loop. Try:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Related Question on SO: [Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Comment: I tried that, with the if statement outside the post function, same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :

  location.reload();
```

also you can call function :

```
  function reload(){location.reload();}
```

and put there :

```
reload();
```