# Reload a page with location.href or window.location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, reload, window.location, location-href

I need to reload a page in a success of an ajax call.

I'm seeing some code (not mine) and there are two ways:

```
success: function(obj) {
  //code
  location.href = location.href;
}
```

or

```
success: function(obj) {
  //code
  window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Is there any difference in the behaviour? I know the difference of both `location` and `window.location` but in terms of do the job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Comment: the `window.location.reload(true);` reloads the page from the server instead of from the cache, `window.location.reload();` would do the same thing as `location.href = location.href;` except for that the `window.location.reload()` includes a post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main difference is follow:

> window.location.reload() reloads the current page with `POST` data, while window.location.href='your url' does not include the `POST` data.

Further more, `window.location.reload(true)` method reload page from the server. And the browser will skip the cache.

For example, I see you are using `success` function from an `AJAX` request.

Suppose you have follow method:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=600)]
public ActionResult Homepage(){
   //code here
   return View();
}
```

If you are using `window.location.href="location_URL"`,then browser cache data for `600` seconds, which means 10 minutes.

On the other hand, if you use `window.location.reload(true)`, then the browser will skip the cache and ,then, reload page from server.

Comment: also, `window.location.href=window.location.href` will not reload the page if there's an anchor (#) in the URL

Comment: Important note: The `forceGet` parameter for `location.reload()` is [only available in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#location.reload_has_no_parameter)!

Answer (score 1):

My version, using above, as a Razor button handler:

```
private async Task  Reset()
{
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.location.reload",true);
}
```