# How to reload page once after form Submition using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have form that works with ajax method to send, and i need to refresh the page after submition then show success of form inside a div.
my question is : is there a way to refresh main page once and then show form success?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.MyForm button[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
    var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
    console.log($frm.serialize());
    $.ajax(
        $frm.attr('action'), 
        {
          method: $frm.attr('method'),
          data: $frm.serialize(),
          success: function(data) { $(".error").html(data)}
   
        }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.error{width:200px; height:50px;border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form class="MyForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
    <select name="Avg">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="error">Show form success here after page reload</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Downvote in 15 sec?? hope you won the hat for that.

Comment: on success of ajax you want to refresh page?

Comment: `window.location.reload()` in success callback method. Why not just submit the form using normal flow?

Comment: @inaz use window.location.reload(); on success..

Comment: @Akshay yes. after submit the form i wanna reload page once

Comment: Whatever @Satpal suggested will work perfectly !

Comment: @Satpal where can i use this callback method?

Comment: if you want to refresh page after submit then why are you using ajax?

Comment: `success: function(data) { $(".error").html(data), window.location.reload();}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(
    $frm.attr('action'), 
    {
        method: $frm.attr('method'),
        data: $frm.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $(".error").html(data)
            location.reload(0)
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.location.reload();
```

OR

```
window.location.href = 'current page url';
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

Answer (score 0):

use **window.location.reload()** as callback method for form submission.