# AngularJS - Reload page 5 seconds once progress bar is 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I would like to reload the page after 5 seconds once the progress bar is 100%

CODE I HAVE IS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin AngularJS Demo
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->

<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo - AngularJS version</title>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for AngularJS. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Generic page styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
<!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css"></noscript>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
<style>
/* Hide Angular JS elements before initializing */
.ng-cloak {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-app="demo" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
<input type="hidden" name="wo" value="1111_">     
     <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="error.asp"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped files ng-cloak">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'processing': file.$processing()}">
                <td data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
                        <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery><img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                        <span data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                            <a data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>{{file.name}}</a>
                            <a data-ng-switch-default data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
                        </span>
                        <span data-ng-switch-default>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <strong data-ng-show="file.error" class="error text-danger">{{file.error}}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">{{file.size | formatFileSize}}</p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending: 'in'}[file.$state()]" data-file-upload-progress="file.$progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="file.$submit()" data-ng-hide="!file.$submit || options.autoUpload" data-ng-disabled="file.$state() == 'pending' || file.$state() == 'rejected'">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-hide="!file.$cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-ng-controller="FileDestroyController" type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy" data-ng-click="file.$destroy()" data-ng-hide="!file.$destroy">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-xBuQ/xzmlsLoJpyjoggmTEz8OWUFM0/RC5BsqQBDX2v5cMvDHcMakNTNrHIW2I5f" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" integrity="sha384-r6jjWwxAypHaESwS5an5J9dkfzwQuKVNV9FZM9B6fnt8PFuY0cVwLhV7BltCZhLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload Angular JS module -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like for the entire page to reload once, or redircet to another URL or send an alert message to the user once the upload has been completed.

Again, thank you for any help with this...

***UPDATE:***

I tried editing the file jquery.fileupload.js and added the following code but it doesn't work or error out..

```
        // Callback for successful uploads:
         done: function (e, data) {
              alert("Upload Done");
window.location.href = "http://www.GOOD.com";
         }, // .bind('fileuploaddone', func);

        // Callback for failed (abort or error) uploads:
         fail: function (e, data) {
             alert("Upload FAILED");
window.location.href = "http://www.FAILED.com";
         }, // .bind('fileuploadfail', func);
```

Comment: Please edit your post, include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and limit your issue to make it specific and clear.

Comment: @compcobalt did my answer help? do you need any more details? I added an example like you asked

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to force a reload. If you pass the same location to `window.location.href`, it won't actually navigate.

I added a minimal working example which also has a text that changes after 2 seconds so we can see the text changing back when the reload happens in the snippet.

1. run the code snippet
2. wait for the text to change (2 seconds)
3. try uploading a file
4. upload should fail because the URL should not work on StackOverflow
5. you'll see the alert, and then the text will revert back to the original text, indicating the reload of the page

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // not needed! only here for the demo
  setTimeout(() => $('#text').text('text changed after 2 seconds').addClass('changed'), 2000);

  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function(e, data) {
      alert('success!');
      location.reload();
    },
    fail: function(e, data) {
      alert('failure!');
      location.reload();
    },
    progressall: function(e, data) { /* ... */ }
  });
});
```

```css
#text {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.changed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>


<!-- This will help us see the reload happening -->
<div id="text">page initial load!</div>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

If you want to make sure you reload from the server and not the browser's cache, pass `true` as the first parameter for `location.reload`:

```js
location.reload(true);
```

### Waiting for 5 seconds before reload

You can do that by using `setTimeout`. replace `location.reload()` with the following snippet:

```js
setTimeout(() => location.reload(), 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that but nothing happens.. no error or anything. I am so sorry, but would it be ok if you provided me an demo?  I think I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @compcobalt provided a working snippet. let me know if this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.location.href` to the same page/url will not work.
Take a look here: [Difference between window.location.href=window.location.href and window.location.reload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405117/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-href-and-window-location)

And for delay, use **`setTimeout()`**

If you are sure that the 'done' function really works, change to

```
done: function (e, data) {
    alert("Upload Done");

    var delayInMilliseconds = 5000; //5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload(); //use 'location.reload(true);' if you want to force reload from server
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
},
```

Best regards,

Brhaka